# Match elements from a character range n times

Tags: r, regex

Assume I have a string like this:

`id = "ce91ffbe-8218-e211-86da-000c29e211a0"`

What regex can I write in R that will verify that this string is 36 characters long and only contains letters, numbers, and dashes?

There is nothing in the documentation on how to use a character range (e.g. `[0-9A-z-]`) with a quantifier (e.g. `{36}`). The following code is always returning `TRUE` regardless of the quantifier. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here...

```
id <- "ce91ffbe-8218-e211-86da-000c29e211a0"

grepl("[0-9A-z-]{36}", id)
#> [1] TRUE

grepl("[0-9A-z-]{34}", id)
#> [1] TRUE
```

This behavior only starts when I add the check for the numbers 0-9 in the character range.

Comment: It returns true because it matches _part_ of the string. Use [`^[0-9a-zA-Z-]{36}$`](https://regex101.com/r/87mouQ/1) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use:

```
^[0-9a-z-]{36}$
```

- `^` Assert position start of line.
- `[0-9a-z-]` Character set for numbers, letters a to z and dashes `-`.
- `{36}` Match preceding pattern 36 times.
- `$` Assert position end of line.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vjfuBi/1).

Comment: Great! Any specific reason or intuition on why you need to assert the start and end?

Comment: Ah. I see from a comment above that, obviously, any time the quantifier is less than the length of the string it will return TRUE since part of the string is matched.

Comment: If you do not use assertions then the expression will match a partial substring in the string. In a string with 37 characters, a pattern without assertions will match the first 36 characters. Since you want exactly 36 characters, you need to use assertions. Note that if you wish to allow capital letters too you can add A-Z to the character set.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following:

```
grepl("^[0-9a-zA-Z-]{36}$",id)
```

***OR***

```
grepl("^[[:alnum:]-]{36}$",id)
```

After running it we will get following output.

```
grepl("^[0-9a-zA-Z-]{36}$",id)
[1] TRUE
```

***Explanation:*** Adding following for only explanation purposes here.

```
grepl("        ##using grepl to check if regex mentioned in it gives TRUE or FALSE result.
^              ##^ means shows starting of the line.
[[:alnum:]-]   ##Mentioning character class [[:alnum:]] with a dash(-) in it means match alphabets with digits and dashes in regex.
{36}           ##Look for only 36 occurences of alphabets with dashes.
$",            ##$ means check from starting(^) to till end of the variable's value.
id)            ##Mentioning id value here.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string can have other characters before or after the target characters, try

```
id <- "ce91ffbe-8218-e211-86da-000c29e211a0"
grepl("^[^[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]-]{36}[^[:alnum:]-]*$", id)
#[1] TRUE

grepl("^[^[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]-]{34}[^[:alnum:]-]*$", id)
#[1] FALSE
```

And this will still work.

```
id2 <- paste0(":+)!#", id)

grepl("^[^[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]-]{36}[^[:alnum:]-]*$", id2)
#[1] TRUE

grepl("^[^[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]-]{34}[^[:alnum:]-]*$", id2)
#[1] FALSE
```